# Notation on a continuous function within Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I need help to understand the meaning of some notation.

Let $q:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function taking positive bounded values such that $q'\in L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}, L^{2}(\Omega))$ and satisfies

$$\sup_{t_{0}\in \mathbb{R}} \int^{t_{0}+1}_{t_{0}}|q'(s)|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}ds<\infty$$

My question is: What is the meaning of $L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}, L^{2}(\Omega))$?

IF IT IS $\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow L^{2}(\Omega)\text{ measurable}: f|_{K}\in L^{2}(K), \forall K\subset\mathbb{R}, K\text{ compact}\},$ then so what is the meaning of $q'$ in terms of $q$?

Thanks in advance. I can accept an answer without reference.

Comment: I understand the confusion here.  When I see this, my first instinct is to read $q'$ as the derivative of $q$, but it seems clear that only continuity is hypothesized for $q$.  Could the author actually have intended to say that $q:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is *differentiable*?

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this down into a few parts. Traditionally $L^2_{loc}(\Omega)=\{f\in L^2(K): K\subset\Omega \,\,\text{is compact}\}$. What you are proposing would imply that $q$ maps functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to a function space, but integration is defined for real valued and complex valued functions so I think the notation is probably another way of writing $L^2_{loc}(\Omega)$. (More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function#Standard_definition). Without knowing the context I would guess that $q'$ is your traditional derivative.

With this in mind, I would read the statement as a function $q$ such that $q'\in L^2_{loc}(\Omega)$ and there exists a constant $M$ such that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\int_t^{t+1}|q'(s)|^2ds \leq M < \infty $$